Laravel - encrypting .env credentials
My client requires the database and email credentials entered in the .env file to be encrypted. Theres no way to convince them otherwise. The app will be hosted and run on their own internal Windows IIS server. They dont want any plain text credentials in configuration files.
My proposed solution would be to encrypt the credentials with a key that I would store in the Windows Environment Variables, and decrypt them at run time on config load.
This would not allow the usage of config caching (not a big deal as the traffic on this app will be very low).
Also, another requirement is that the key must be configurable by them.
Is this an acceptable solution ? Is there another way ?
Thanks.

This is not only an acceptable solution, it is a recommended one by github. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-for-github-actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#storing-large-secrets

Your solution of encrypting the credentials and storing the key in Windows Environment Variables can work, but it has some limitations in terms of flexibility and scalability. Given your client's need for security and configurability, a tool like HashiCorp Vault might be a better fit.
